# care-o-bot simulation fails on indigo / ubuntu 14.04 (all packages up to date as of 20160316)

Tags: ros, care-o-bot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SwE8Fvzb6Y
the latest version as of (20160316) is broken?
anybody managed to work with it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229240/care-o-bot-simulation-fails-on-indigo-/-ubuntu-14.04-(all-packages-up-to-date-as-of-20160316)/) by [greg herts.ac.uk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26300/greg-herts.ac.uk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-16**:
Please add more information: from `apt-get` or from source? Which commands do you execute? What is the expected behaviour? What is the behaviour you experience? Which robot (you have cob4 and cob3 in the video)?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-16**:
From the 12min video we mainly see terminals, the few glimpses of `rviz`, a few glimpses of `gazebo` which seems fine...

What do you want to do and what does not work?

**Comment by [greg herts.ac.uk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26300/greg-herts.ac.uk/) on 2016-03-16**:
hi!
I got it from apt-get
the commands are here
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1D3kirMhOmmdbQGCCTGCvioP3tMIhid20cN8izyi75tw/edit?usp=sharing
I tried all the robots on simulation
the problem is that the robot simply does not move when there is a command like 2-d pose estimate etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the release version the robot is not moving because there is a conflict with the cmd_vel topic name. The navigation publishes the twist command to /base_controller/command and gazebo is subscribed to /base/twist_controller/command.

The problem is already fixed but, at the moment, you have to use the actual source version.
You can create a cob3-2_navigation.rosinstall file with the following lines:

```
 - git:
    uri: 'https://github.com/ipa320/cob_common.git'
    local-name: cob_common
    version: indigo_dev
- git:
    uri: 'https://github.com/ipa320/cob_control.git'
    local-name: cob_control
    version: indigo_dev
- git:
    uri: 'https://github.com/ipa320/cob_driver.git'
    local-name: cob_driver
    version: indigo_dev
- git:
    uri: 'https://github.com/ipa320/cob_robots.git'
    local-name: cob_robots
    version: indigo_dev
- git:
    uri: 'https://github.com/ipa320/cob_navigation.git'
    local-name: cob_navigation
    version: indigo_dev
```

And install the necessary packages using the commands:

```
rosinstall ~/YourWorkSpace/src cob3-2_navigation.rosinstall
rosdep install --from-path ~/YourWorkSpace/src -i -y
source ~/YourWorkSpace/devel/setup
```

---

Originally posted by [NadiaHammoudeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26308/nadiahammoudeh/) with karma: 46 on 2016-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2